# datatable callback

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use jquery datatable in my application. I managed to get it to work perfectly fine with server data updates

The javascript used to create the table looks like this

```
jQuery(function() {
    return $('#example').dataTable({
      sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
      bProcessing: true,
      bServerSide: true,
      bRetrieve: true
    });
}).call(this);
```

The problem is I need to add a hook in the javascript to enable me to update another page element after the table data updated from the server

Comment: not sure, try `fnInitComplete` if that wont work , try some other from here http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fnDrawCallback`](http://datatables.net/ref/fnDrawCallback) is the callback for you:

```
"fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
    // Update the element
}
```